# Cannot open project.exe for writing, access to the path is denied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bitdefender

I am developing a console application that worked fine yesterday.
As of today when I build the application I get the following error:
`Cannot open <projectpath>\obj\debug\net471\<project>.exe for writing. Access to the path <projectpath>\obj\debug\net471\<project>.exe is denied`.

I noticed that Bitdefender Endpoint Security had put this file into quarantine but after removing it from quarantine, and making sure that it would not do that again, the problem persists.

I have already cleaned the solution, deleted everything in the `obj` folder, restored nuget packages and built the solution again, but I still receive the same error.

I also made sure that the location was not read only and other files are added to that location when the project is built.

I noticed that the executable was added to the quarantine of BitDefender Endpoint Security again. I am not in a position to either disable or remove Bitdefender and the Endpoint version ahs very limited options.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up asking the system administrator to at least temporarily uninstall Bitdefender and now my projects build with no issues.